# How to disable Wifi when not used in background android?

Tags: android, android-service, android-wifi

I want to disable the wifi when not connect to any network. It will be running in the background and disabled anytime when wifi are enable and not used. How can I do that? Please give me some advice. I have to use Foreground or Service/ Broadcast Receiver.

Comment: `I want to disable the wifi when not connect to any network` If you do that, you'll never re-enable it again (as you'll never be connected)

Comment: @njzk2 You mean when i connect to network in future. It's disabling the wifi itself. I think there will be exception when first time connect to network. It will work after wifi is disconnect for a fews min. How do you think?

Comment: I think it is an out of the box feature as for android has this in the advanced options for wifi. It allows you to fall back to the default connection when the device idles.

Comment: I think most of device doesn't support this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested in [Tasker](http://tasker.dinglisch.net). It can automate basically every setting in Android.

You can make a profile `State> Variable Value> %WIFI=on` Action: `If "Wifi Info" %WIFII !contains "CONNECTION" then Net> Toggle Wifi> Off`

You can also do this in Java with a bit more work. I can provide details on that if you request.

And also if you're lazy you can download neat little apps that take care of it for you: [Auto Wifi Off](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ws.inaction.android.autowifioff&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dplay%20store%20wifi%20off&pcampaignid=APPU_1_BZcuVejDOo_7gwSppoCYCw)

Hope that helps

Comment: I think Tasker is bad UI. It's difficut to understand for non-programmer.

Comment: How to known when wifi is not connected to net in Background? BroadcastReceiver wifi.Change_State??

Comment: Look at the app I mentioned. You can decompile it and see what his receiver code looks like. You can even decompile apks online: decompileandroid.com, takes 2 minutes

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm getting some problems. Can you help me? [Problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29677601/android-checkboxpreference-doesnt-work-with-broadcast-reciever)