# Android CheckboxPreference doesn't work with Broadcast Reciever

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-broadcast

I'm trying to disable Wifi when not connect to any network after a min. But getting some problems. 
When i run the app. It start working and try to disable wifi that's not connect to any network. It's mean I can't stop it. I have a Preference Activity with `CheckBoxPreference`. It's the setting to turn on/off this feature. I want to only work when user checked the checkbox. If uncheck, stop working. But right now, It's working anytime out of control. CheckBox is doesn't work for turn on/off feature.
Here is my code. What is wrong with mycode? Please help me.

MyActivity.java

```
public class MyActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.prefes);

        Preference preference = (Preference) findPreference(Strings.SETTINGS_WIFI_TIMEOUT);

        preference
                .setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                            Object object) {
                        if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(object)) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                    MyService.class);
                            startService(intent);
                        } else {
                            stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                    MyService.class));
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Stop service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });

    }
}
```

MyService.java

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    int mStartMode; // indicates how to behave if the service is killed
    IBinder mBinder; // interface for clients that bind
    boolean mAllowRebind; // indicates whether onRebind should be used

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // A client is binding to the service with bindService()
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
        super.onRebind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        // The service is starting, due to a call to startService()
        Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) MyService.this
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null
                && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

        if (isConnected) {

        } else {
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
        }

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "service done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

WifiWatcher.java

```
public class WiFiWatcher extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null
                && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

        if (isConnected) {

        } else {
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
        }

    }
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.example.service.WiFiWatcher" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Comment: @dora Yes, I have. I updated Manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be entering both these permissions also

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: I have already. My problems is not this. I'm facing that CheckBoxPreference doesn't work. I want to start process on checkBoxPreference is checked. and then Unchecked stop process working.